# Comma separated keyword search

Tags: angular, pipe, angular2-directives

I am using a filter condition to filter rows in my table.

```
<tr *ngFor="let result  of mf.data | filter:filter; let i = index">
```

We use ng2-search-filter

Currently, its filtering based on keyword, but i want to filter rows when I enter the keyword in comma seperated format.

How i can change the above line to make it work?

Full table

```
<table id="groups" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" [mfData]="resultData" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage"
                        [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
                      <thead>
                      <tr role="row">

                        <th>  <mfDefaultSorter by="HostName">Host Name</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <!-- <th><mfDefaultSorter by="SupportDL">Support DL</mfDefaultSorter></th>  -->
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="Connectivity">Connectivity</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="RDPStatus">RDP Status</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="MemoryStatus">Memory Status</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="CPUStatus">CPU Status</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="ServiceStatus">Service Status</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="ServiceLogStatus">Service Log Status</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="DiskStatus">Disk Status</mfDefaultSorter></th>
                        <th><mfDefaultSorter by="LogTime">Log Time</mfDefaultSorter></th>


                        <!-- <th>Actions</th> -->
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody *ngIf="resultData.length>0">
                      <tr *ngFor="let result  of mf.data | filter:filter; let i = index">

                        <td>{{result.HostName}}</td>
                        <!-- <td>{{result.SupportDL}}</td> -->
                        <td>{{result.Connectivity}}</td>
                        <td>{{result.RDPStatus}}</td>
                        <td>{{result.MemoryStatus}}</td>
                        <td>{{result.CPUStatus}}</td>
                        <td><pre>{{result.ServiceStatus}}</pre></td>
                        <td>{{result.ServiceLogStatus}}</td>
                        <td><pre>{{result.DiskStatus}}</pre></td>
                        <td>{{result.LogTime}}</td>

                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tr *ngIf="resultData.length <=0"><td colspan="10"> No Data Found</td></tr>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="8">
                                <mfBootstrapPaginator></mfBootstrapPaginator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If filter is a simple input :

```
<input type="query" [(ngModel)]="filter">
```

Then you don't change your HTML.

Since you didn't post your actual filter (and didn't mark your previous issue as resolved, thank you for that BTW), I'm going to use the filter I gave you and change it a bit :

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: true
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Object[], args: string): any {
    console.log(args);

    if (!items || !items.length) { return []; }

    if (!args) { return items; }

    return items
      .filter(item => Object.keys(item)
        .some(key => args.split(',').some(arg => item[key].toLowerCase().includes(arg.toLowerCase())))
      );
  }
}
```

And [here is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nbkj1?file=src/app/filter.pipe.ts), and the proof it works with an image :

[image: stackblitz screenshot]

Comment: we use ng2-search-filter

Comment: Yeah maybe you should state that in your original question ... And as you can see, you don't need it.

Comment: I tried the logic "A , D"  ideally it should display both rows , but it is not listing any rows

Comment: Please fix that issue so that i can accpet your answer thanks

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, both rows are being displayed. I used your own filter to create this one, and it didn't accept spaces.

Comment: when i search A , D i need to see row containing A and D both,but not showing any records

Comment: And as I said, it doesn't accept spaces, as your original filter. Remove the spaces and it will work.

Comment: I'm on my phone and it works like a charm, as you can see in my edit. You'll have to make at least some bit of an effort there.